# Combine form based authentication in ASP.NET with direct authentication trough URL GET parameters

Tags: asp.net, authorization

I'm new in ASP.NET and already got a lot of answers here searching on google (THX!).
My task is now to build a website, where authentication is required, so I choosed form based authetication, which is working well.
I need to add functionality, when user can click on link and after redirecting to that website he will get automatically authorized based on GET parameters.

For example:
    http://www.mysite.com/login.aspx?username=xxx&password=yyy

So after clicking on such link he will skip login page and continue to page behind.

Could you please help me with that question?

P.S. I'm aware, that it is not secure and username with password will be visible as clear text, but here we are talking about generated username and password which will be available just for one day and it is required to identify user to do one request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like.

Make sure the username and password are in the `querystring`, and then assign them to a `username` and `password` varaible.

c#

```
if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, true);
}
else { // not authenticated. do something }
```

vb.net

```
If FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password) Then
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true)
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, true)
Else
    ' not authenticated. do something.
End If
```

For this to work you will need to import/using System.Web.Security. The `true` value tells your authentication to set a persistent cookie value.

Comment: I am sure, that this is the answer I am looking for, just one more question: _FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password)_ return always false, how can I link it to the autherization used in login form? Or if I do authorization process myself, is it enough to use _SetAuthCookie_ and _RedirecFromLoginPage_? Because it seems to be working, I am just not sure, if it is secure.

Comment: If you do your own authentication, then it is enough just to call the `SetAuthCookie` and/or `RedirectFromLoginPage` :)

Comment: Thank you a lot a for a fast and really usefull response!

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `SQL Server` as the `database`, the easiest way is to use `ASP.NET membership` provider. By using that you will be able to `authenticate` user in an effective way. Here you can use [Aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to create required batabase tables. There is a good explanation about [Creating a Web Site with Membership and User Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx)

Hope this will help